# Error running a Python program in Terminal

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Python program in Terminal, but I face the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0iQa.png)

```py
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 /home/pi/Cascades2/03_face_recognition.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Cascades2/03_face_recognition.py", line 15, in <module>
    recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /home/pi/opencv-python/opencv_contrib/modules/face/src/facerec.cpp:61: error: (-2:Unspecified error) File can't be opened for reading! in function 'read'
```

The Python program works well when I run it with Thonny.

What's the problem?

Here's the program (03_face_recognition.py) code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

relay = 23
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay, 0)

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#initiate id counter
id = 0

# names related to ids: example ==> Jenifer: id=1,  etc
names = ['None', 'Jenifer', 'Luciola'] 

# Initialize and start realtime video capture
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('ipcamera')
frame_rate = 1
prev = 0

# Define min window size to be recognized as a face
minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)

while True:
    
    time_elapsed = time.time() - prev
    res, image = cam.read()

    if time_elapsed > 1./frame_rate:
        prev = time.time()

    ret, img =cam.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
        gray,
        scaleFactor = 1.2,
        minNeighbors = 5,
        minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
       )

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        # Check if confidence is less than 100 ==> "0" is perfect match 
        if (confidence < 80):
            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
            GPIO.output(relay, 1)
            print("Ouverture du portail", datetime.datetime.now(), id, confidence)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(relay, 0)
            cam.release()
            time.sleep(30)
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture('ipcamera')
            
        else:
            GPIO.output(relay, 0)
        
        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  
    
    cv2.imshow('camera',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break
    
# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hello Florian, and welcome! As you can see someone has already reformatted your error message. Can you make more sense of it? The title of your question is very generic, do you think you can describe the error better when re-reading your error mesasge?

Comment: the error message is quite clear; the `yml` file cannot be located by the module listed there; difference between the paths inside your environment vs. outside

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your help. I can't post my error message as code, as I reach a code/description ratio limit to post my question. The first error is fixed, I updated with a second error that appears.

Comment: @Florian Please  dont delete your previous error and post a new error. If so add the second error so we can understand what happened. Otherwise see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It’s likely to do with what the current working directory is.

In your error you are in your home directory. If you run the program with ‘thonny’ I imagine that ‘thonny’ will set the script’s folder.

When you specify the file to open you are using a relative path. Maybe you could use the absolute path instead.

Comment: The first error is fixed, I updated my question with a second error that appears.

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not how it works here. Your question is preserved here just in case a future programmer has the same problem. If you have a different problem, then you need to ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy fix, I had to replace `trainer/trainer.yml` by `/home/pi/Cascades2/trainer/trainer.yml`, the absolute path.